# react-hook-form and Material UI FormControl

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hook-form

So I am trying to register some radio buttons for my form, however it will not register.

```
<FormControl component="fieldset" inputRef={register({ required: true })}>
  <FormLabel component="legend">Promoting</FormLabel>
  <RadioGroup aria-label="promoting" name="promoting" value={promoting} onChange={handleChange} inputRef={register({ required: true })}>
    <FormControlLabel value="business" control={<Radio  />} label="Business" />
    <FormControlLabel value="nonprofit" control={<Radio />} label="Non-Profit" />
    <FormControlLabel value="event" control={<Radio  />} label="Event" />
  </RadioGroup>
</FormControl>
```

I am wondering what I am doing wrong

Full code:

```
export default function BuildAd() {
  const [promoting, setValue] = React.useState('female');

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setValue(event.target.value);
  };

  const { register, handleSubmit, errors } = useForm();

  const onSubmit = data => console.log(data);
  console.log(errors);
  
  return (
    <div style={{ padding: 16, margin: 'auto', maxWidth: 600 }}>
    <CssBaseline />
    
    <Typography variant="h5" align="center" component="h2" gutterBottom>
      Create your campaign
    </Typography>
         <Paper style={{ padding: 16 }}>
              <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
                <input type="text" placeholder="First name" name="First name" ref={register({required: true, maxLength: 80})} />
                <input type="text" placeholder="Last name" name="Last name" ref={register({required: true, maxLength: 100})} />
                <input type="text" placeholder="Email" name="Email" ref={register({required: true, pattern: /^\S+@\S+$/i})} />
                <input type="tel" placeholder="Mobile number" name="Mobile number" ref={register({required: true, minLength: 6, maxLength: 12})} />
                <select name="Title" ref={register({ required: true })}>
                  <option value="Mr">Mr</option>
                  <option value="Mrs">Mrs</option>
                  <option value="Miss">Miss</option>
                  <option value="Dr">Dr</option>
                </select>

                <input name="Developer" type="radio" value="Yes" ref={register({ required: true })}/>
                <input name="Developer" type="radio" value="No" ref={register({ required: true })}/>


                <Typography variant="h5">What are you Advertising</Typography>
                    <Box m={2}/>
                    <FormControl component="fieldset" inputRef={register({ required: true })}>
                    <FormLabel component="legend">Promoting</FormLabel>
                    <RadioGroup aria-label="promoting" name="promoting" value={promoting} onChange={handleChange} inputRef={register({ required: true })}>
                      <FormControlLabel value="business" control={<Radio inputRef={register({ required: true })} />} label="Business" />
                      <FormControlLabel value="nonprofit" control={<Radio inputRef={register({ required: true })} />} label="Non-Profit" />
                      <FormControlLabel value="event" control={<Radio inputRef={register({ required: true })} />} label="Event" />
                    </RadioGroup>
                  </FormControl>
                  
                <input type="submit" />
            </form>
      </Paper>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can fallback on controllable components by using [`Controller`](https://react-hook-form.com/api/usecontroller/controller) if it doesn't work.

In your case, I suspect it's because the `name` props passed to your `RadioGroup` [is not the same](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/ebeb1492b5e645eccdea920fbbf561fe2a0c3031/packages/material-ui/src/RadioGroup/RadioGroup.js#L56-L59) as the `name` attribute when passed into native inputs like `input` or `select`.

### `react-hook-form` V7

```
const { handleSubmit, control } = useForm({
  defaultValues: {
    promoting2: '',
  },
});
```

```
<FormControl component="fieldset">
  <FormLabel component="legend">Promoting</FormLabel>
  <Controller
    rules={{ required: true }}
    control={control}
    name="promoting2"
    render={({ field }) => (
      <RadioGroup {...field}>
        <FormControlLabel
          value="business"
          control={<Radio />}
          label="Business"
        />
        <FormControlLabel
          value="nonprofit"
          control={<Radio />}
          label="Non-Profit"
        />
        <FormControlLabel
          value="event"
          control={<Radio />}
          label="Event"
        />
      </RadioGroup>
    )}
  />
</FormControl>
```

[image: Edit 64042394/react-hook-form-and-material-ui-formcontrol (forked)]

### `react-hook-form` V6

```js
const { register, handleSubmit, errors, control } = useForm({
  promoting: '',
});
const onSubmit = (data) => alert(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
```

```js
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
  <FormControl component="fieldset">
    <FormLabel component="legend">Promoting</FormLabel>
    <Controller
      rules={{ required: true }}
      control={control}
      name="promoting"
      as={
        <RadioGroup>
          <FormControlLabel
            value="business"
            control={<Radio />}
            label="Business"
          />
          <FormControlLabel
            value="nonprofit"
            control={<Radio />}
            label="Non-Profit"
          />
          <FormControlLabel
            value="event"
            control={<Radio />}
            label="Event"
          />
        </RadioGroup>
      }
    />
  </FormControl>

  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

If you want to read the value when `onChange` fires, you cannot do that when passing the element to the `as` props:

```
<Controller
  {...}
  as={
    <MyComponent
      onChange={handleChange} // handleChange will never be called
    />
  }
/>
```

The reason is because `Controller` will copy the element that you pass in and pass its own `onChange` props that will override yours. See [here](https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form/blob/c18ceee1975651c14e1d33fc420f5eece0824f1f/src/controller.tsx#L14-L19) and [here](https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form/blob/c18ceee1975651c14e1d33fc420f5eece0824f1f/src/useController.ts#L201).

To fix that problem, you need to use another way to pass the element down by using `render` props to gain more control on how you should render your components.

```js
<Controller
  rules={{ required: true }}
  control={control}
  name="promoting2"
  render={({ name, onBlur, onChange, value }) => (
    <RadioGroup
      value={value}
      onBlur={onBlur}
      onChange={(e) => {
        onChange(e);
        console.log(e.target.value); // will be called this time
      }}
    >
      <FormControlLabel
        value="business"
        control={<Radio />}
        label="Business"
      />
      {...}
    </RadioGroup>
  )}
/>
```

[image: Edit 64042394/react-hook-form-and-material-ui-formcontrol]

Comment: In the Live Demo, and in the code above, the `onChange` `handleChange` handler doesn't seem to be called. If you try `console.log`'ing in the `onChange`, or comment out the `setValue` call in your Live Demo, it works just the same. Do you know this is happening? Thanks

Comment: @GregSadetsky I updated the answer and live demo regarding your concern.

Comment: Thank you @NearHuscarl! Using the `render` props works well. Cheers

Comment: The answer does not seem to work using typescript. At this point, I am unsure whether the problem is on my side or not, but the sample is not applicable in my case.

Comment: @LanVukušič can you spin a codesandbox with the error? What's the error message? What's your RHF version? I keep getting downvoted on these kind of answers and want to update once to address the issue.

Comment: This code will not preset value in case if we want to use `reset` call

Comment: @abhilash I fixed it in my answer and the codesandbox. You need to set `defaultValue` in when calling `useForm` and remove the one from MUI.

Comment: This solution logs an error message in console: MUI: A component is changing the uncontrolled value state of RadioGroup to be controlled.
Elements should not switch from uncontrolled to controlled (or vice versa).
Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled RadioGroup element for the lifetime of the component.
The nature of the state is determined during the first render. It's considered controlled if the value is not `undefined`.

Comment: Figured out I was missing the default value. It cannot be undefined.